# Symfony 4 Redirect without a custom controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

so the problem which I'm facing is, that I'm not able to use wildcards inside of my redirects configured in the routing.yml

```yaml
homepage:
  path: /test/{wildcard}
  controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
  defaults:
    path: /{wildcard}
    permanent: true
```

In the default path I need to get the wildcard path. So e.g test/wildcard should redirect to /wildcard.
But what Symfony is doing is, that it's redirecting to /{wildcard}.
So how can I get the wildcard parameter?

Comment: The problem is, that `path: /{wildcard}` under `defaults:` does not support wildcards, and instead reads it as a literal value to be used by the RedirectController. You could create your own RedirectController that reads in the wildcard provided as parameter in the path to the action and use that to dynamically determine the target path instead of specifying it. The original [`redirectAction`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/RedirectController.php#L57) could be a reference for this.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. So in order to solve the problem I created a controller on my own and used it as parameter in the controller param in the config above.

To get the wildcard parameter in the controller I did this:
```$request->get('wildcard')
```

Comment: You could also directly add it to the method signature: `public function redirect(string $wildcard) { ... }` or use `$request->query->get('wildcard')` using `$request->get()` can be surprising since [it looks at different parameter bags in a specific order](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L685-L699). Probably not a big deal here, but it helps prevent weird side effects and is recommended (see docblock).

Comment: Hmm, don't think this is possible to ad the wildcard to the function signature because symfony is not able to resolve the wildcard param to the given path from the url. It's just passes /{wildcard} as parameter if you add it to the signature, not the real value. Or do you know how to get the given wildcard path in the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to give an answer to my question.
The solution is the following:
You need to create a custom `RedirectController`, which is able to handle
wildcards within a route.

This is what the the controller can look like:

```
<?php


namespace Custom\RedirectBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RedirectController
{

    public function urlRedirectAction(
        Request $request,
        bool $permanent = false,
        string $route = '',
        array $dynamicRoutePath =
        []
    ): RedirectResponse {
        $statusCode = $permanent ? 301 : 302;
        if ('' !== $route) {
            $url = "/".$route;
            if (!empty($dynamicRoutePath)) {
                $url = $this->getPath($request, $dynamicRoutePath, $url);
            }

            return new RedirectResponse($url, $statusCode);
        }
        $route = $this->getPath($request, $dynamicRoutePath);

        return new RedirectResponse($route, $statusCode);
    }

    private function getPath(Request $request, array $path, string $url = ''): string
    {
        foreach ($path as $pathParameter) {
            $pathconfig = $request->get($pathParameter);
            $url        = $url."/".$pathconfig;
        }

        return $url;
    }

}
```

Configuration in routing.yml:

```
magazin_category_slug:
  path: /magazin/{category}/{slug}
  controller: CustomRedirectBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
  defaults:
    permanent: true
    route: newBaseRoute
    dynamicRoutePath:
      - category
```